# INNER JOIN (SELECT FROM WHERE) returns error: Unknown column in field list

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

a column is unknown based from my inner join

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'storage_rates.s_rate' in 'field
>   list'

```
select 
    entry_id,
    contr_list.contr_no,  
    contr_type.type_code,
    storage_rates.s_rate
from entry_list
left join contr_list 
    on contr_list.contr_id = entry_list.contr_id
left join contr_type 
    on contr_type.type_id = contr_list.contr_type_id
inner join (SELECT contr_type_id FROM storage_rates WHERE rate_stat = 1) s 
    on s.contr_type_id = contr_type.type_id;
```

the expected output is storage_rates.s_rate = based on if storage_rates.rate_stat = 1 from inner join

Comment: Add `s_rate` to the `SELECT` clause of your inner `SELECT`, and reference it as `s.s_rate`...

Comment: You are selecting contr_type_id  in the inner join sub query so why the surprise?

Comment: You have not joined `storage_rates` table in your main query block. Instead, you are accessing `storage_rates` table in a Derived table (subquery), with an alias `s`. Use `s.s_rate`. You will also need to put `s_rate` in the select clause of your subquery

Comment: Thanks , I do need to use alias used in inner join when accessing the column, and column should be also inside subquery. problem is solve! @MadhurBhaiya